# How to add a registration page to log-in page it?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a new android developer trying to create a log-in and register page. I have created both Log-in and Registration pages but i don't know how to add the registration page with the main log-in interface. I have tried to add it but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone let me clear on how to add a page X with another page Y.

Your answers to guide me are welcome.

Comment: if you want to have both functionality on same page than create a single layout for that only.

Answer (score 1):

Create a button in login page suppose btn_login.Then

```
 btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i=new Intent(Loginpage.this,Registration.class);
                    startActivity(i);   


                }
            });
```

In this way you can connect two pages using Intent.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can make use of Intents ,Assuming that you have two activities and A button named **buttonReg**

**1.Login Page (Login.java)
2.Registration Page(Register.java)**
Create an Intent
For the register page like like

```
Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Register.class);
```

and start activity in the button click like

```
    buttonReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
    startActivity(in);
}
    });
```

And do not forget to add the Activity to your Manifest.xml
For more information about intents goto [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)